# Sum to infinite terms if $|x|<1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

Sum to infinite terms if $|x|<1$

$$S=\dfrac{1}{\left(1-x\right)\cdot\left(1-x^3\right)}+\dfrac{x^2}{\left(1-x^3\right)\cdot\left(1-x^5\right)}+\dfrac{x^4}{\left(1-x^5\right)\cdot\left(1-x^7\right)}+...............$$

My attempt is as follows:

$$T_n=\dfrac{x^{\left(2n-2\right)}}{\left(1-x^{\left(2n-1\right)}\right)\cdot\left(1-x^{\left(2n+1\right)}\right)}$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}T_n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^{\left(2n-2\right)}}{\left(1-x^{\left(2n-1\right)}\right)\cdot\left(1-x^{\left(2n+1\right)}\right)}$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}T_n=\dfrac{1}{x\cdot\left(1-x^2\right)}\cdot\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^{\left(2n-1\right)}\cdot\left(1-x^2\right)}{\left(1-x^{\left(2n-1\right)}\right)\cdot\left(1-x^{\left(2n+1\right)}\right)}$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}T_n=\dfrac{1}{x\cdot\left(1-x^2\right)}\cdot\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\left(1-x^{\left(2n+1\right)}\right)-\left(1-x^{\left(2n-1\right)}\right)}{\left(1-x^{\left(2n-1\right)}\right)\cdot\left(1-x^{\left(2n+1\right)}\right)}$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}T_n=\dfrac{1}{x\cdot\left(1-x^2\right)}\cdot\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{\left(1-x^{\left(2n-1\right)}\right)}-\dfrac{1}{\left(1-x^{\left(2n+1\right)}\right)}\right)$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}T_n=\dfrac{1}{x\cdot\left(1-x^2\right)}\cdot\left(\dfrac{1}{1-x}-\dfrac{1}{1-x^3}+\dfrac{1}{1-x^3}-\dfrac{1}{1-x^5}+............\right)$$

All terms will cancel out to infinity except the first term.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}T_n=\dfrac{1}{x\cdot\left(1-x^2\right)}\cdot\dfrac{1}{1-x}$$

But surprisingly answer given is

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}T_n=\dfrac{1}{\left(1-x^2\right)}\cdot\dfrac{1}{1-x}$$

I checked multiple times but not able to understand the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N\left(\frac{1}{1-x^{2n-1}} - \frac{1}{1-x^{2n+1}}\right)
= \lim_{N \to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{1-x} - \frac{1}{1-x^{2N+1}}\right)
= \frac{1}{1-x} - 1 = \frac{x}{1-x}.$$

Comment: ,all terms will cancel out to infinity, so only term will be remaining, right?

Comment: He's saying the telescoping sum will approach $\frac{1}{1-x}-1$.  It's not that the last term disappears.  It approaches $1$.

Comment: but how it can be , we are summing to infinity, $\dfrac{1}{1-x}-\dfrac{1}{1-x^3}+\dfrac{1}{1-x^3}-\dfrac{1}{1-x^5}+\dfrac{1}{1-x^5}--------- $ till infinity.

You can clearly see , every term is getting cancelled out except the first term, so till infinity only one term will remain, that is how we prove the sum for infinite geometric series, do you take the last term over there, no right, then why here,? We would have taken the last term if we had sum upto n terms.

Comment: @user3290550 By the same argument, you would say $1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + \cdots = 0$, I presume? But the partial sums are $1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, \ldots$, which is a sequence that does not converge.

Comment: See I am also trying to learn, because I have done multiple questions of such type of series and never got this issue while summing to infinity, see here is one question $T_n=\dfrac{n}{1+n^2+n^4}$ , its answer is 1/2 ,just solve it, you will get to know

Comment: @user3290550 A telescoping sum of the form $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n - a_{n+1})$ is defined as $\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N (a_n - a_{n+1})$, the limit of the partial sums. Due to the telescoping, thet $N$th partial sum can be written as $a_1 - a_{N+1}$. In many other situations, $a_{N+1}$ tends to zero as $N \to \infty$, so that the original series is $\lim_{N \to \infty} (a_1 - a_{N+1}) = a_1$, which is why you think you can just throw away the last term. In the current question, however, we have $a_{N+1} \to 1$.